# How do I loop through files in Python to identify and count duplicates?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of files for which I would like to record the number of instances a file occurs. Here is a sample of the data I have:

[image: Sample of the data]

I want the code to run through all these files and record output as follows in a separate excel file:

```
    Name               Date      Number of Files
    MarketDataServer   30012013  2
    MarketDataServer   30032013  1
    .
    .
    .
    .
    NetStat            01012013  5
    NetStat            01022012  3
```

Is there any way in which this can be done using a python script?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You will have to look at the `os.listdir` module to iterate through the files, and through `re` module for extracting info from the filename pattern.

Comment: This question does not show any effort/research towards creating a solution. Solving this problem with Python is very much possible, but without knowing what you are struggling with, it is difficult to assist.
As noted in @ashish's comment, os.listdir will give you a list of filenames.
a third-party library like openpyxl will enable you to write data/content to an Excel spreadsheet. Although, depending on what you want to do, a comma separated value (CSV) file is probably sufficient, in which case, the csv module in Python works just fine.

Comment: The answer to your question is : yes, it can be done. But we will not do it for you. Try to write some code, then if you have an issue we will help you out.

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil, will give it a shot for sure.

Comment: @E.Ducateme, thanks for the suggestions. I will use the tips while building my code.

Comment: @NabIlovich, I understand completely. I usually try building the code myself to learn but I am in a bit of a hurry this time. Nevertheless, I will try posting the final code myself once it is built. Sorry!

Answer (score -2):

you can create something like:

```
import os
d = {}
for current_dir in [dir1, dir2, dir3..]  # iterates over directories with files
    files = os.listdir(current_dir)

    for fi in files:
        if fi in d.keys():
            d[fi] += 1  # it is already there, let's increment
        else:
           d[fi] = 1  # it is a new file

for k, v in d.items():  # let's print the file stats
    print 'File:', k, 'count':' v
```

Comment: Thanks @Radekhofman. It sort of helped. However, it reads each file type individually. I want to be able to count .GZ and .GZ_1 under the same file name together. Anyway I can do that?